# Android achartengine setDisplayChartValues crashes App

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I just want to display the Y values right above the chart line, I found that the method to do this is setting setDisplayChartValues to true. However when I use it the app crashes with the following error message: ***java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3*** being 3 the number of points in the chart.

```
public class LineGraph {

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private double max = 0;
private double min = 999;

public View getView(Context ctx, String[] dates, double[] y){

    for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++){

        if(y[i] > max)
            max = y[i];

        if(y[i] < min)
            min = y[i];
    }

    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("progress");
    for(int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){

        String temp[] = dates[i].split("/");

        int year = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        Date dt = cal.getTime();

        series.add(dt, y[i]);
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.setLineWidth(3f); // Girth of the chart line

    //mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    //mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    //mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    //mRenderer.setXTitle("dias");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Weight (Kg)");
    mRenderer.setPointSize(5f);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(17f);

    //Setting the max and min height of the chart
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max + 2);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(min - 2);

    View view = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(ctx, dataset, mRenderer, "dd/MMM/yyyy");

    return view;
}
```

by using renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true); the app crashes, without it, works just fine.

Comment: What version of ACE are you using?

Comment: Dan, I'm using the 1.0.0 version.

Comment: Same Problem over here .. still not working with 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you upgrade to the latest 1.1.0 release as this issue has been fixed a while ago. You can download the version [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: I upgraded to version 1.1.0 but the problem remains :s

Comment: I've met the same problem. Have you found solution? (Version 1.1.0)

Log is here:

07-11 13:41:05.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12539): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5
07-11 13:41:05.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12539):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange issue, but adding data to your `TimeSeries` out of order will cause this. I used a `TreeMap` to mimic the `TimeSeries`. Then, just iterate through the keys of your sorted `TreeMap` and add the data to the `TimeSeries` that way.